# groovy executeUpdate throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: sql, groovy

I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -5 on the following groovy .

Problem seems to happen only when I use nested select with the parameters ( if I use only parameters or only nested select it works, but not both at the same time)

```
  conn.executeUpdate(
            "UPDATE sc_commit_detail d1\n" +
                    "SET d1.commit_status = ?\n" +
                    "WHERE d1.sc_commit_detail_id IN (" +
                            "SELECT d2.sc_commit_detail_id " +
                            "FROM sc_commit_detail d2 " +
                            "WHERE d2.sc_commit_detail_id = 143661" +
                    ")"
            ,['APPLIED'] )
```

Tried same query in pl/sql and it works.

Note that this works in the code (because I don't use parameters):

```
    conn.executeUpdate(
            "UPDATE sc_commit_detail d1\n" +
                    "SET d1.commit_status = 'APPLIED'\n" +
                    "WHERE d1.sc_commit_detail_id IN (" +
                            "SELECT d2.sc_commit_detail_id " +
                            "FROM sc_commit_detail d2 " +
                            "WHERE d2.sc_commit_detail_id = 143661" +
                    ")"

       )
```

And also this (because I don't use nested select):

```
 conn.executeUpdate(
            "UPDATE sc_commit_detail d1\n" +
                    "SET d1.commit_status = ?\n" +
                    "WHERE d1.sc_commit_detail_id = 143661",
            ['APPLIED']
        )
```

What am I doing wrong?

It's for Oracle DB, and I simplified it for this question to show the problem, I must use both nested and parameters

Comment: Please try with named parameter like instead of `?` use `:status` and pass parameter as `[status: 'APPLIED']`

Comment: Tried it, exactly the same error

Comment: Tried your code, it works correctly in my environment, and the record in the db is updated. I think more details are required (code, stack trace, version info, db structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the problem, it's actually a known bug in jdbc7 driver version 12.1.0.2.0 (and also some other versions).

After using jdbc6 version 11.2.0.2.0 it works (someone in oracle forums had the same problem and this version worked for him)